# Blue band on screen of Galaxy ACE Android

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, screen, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a blue band across the middle of my Galaxy Ace 55830i *Gingerbread.XXLD3* phone and cannot find out why.

I have tried to check if it is a video still playing or something streaming but I have been unsuccessful in sorting out what the problem is.

Comment: Does the blue band show up when you are booting the phone (on the initial logo and startup animation)? Or only after you have started the phone completely up?

Comment: Blue band - are you referring to when playing a video?

Comment: Try taking a screenshot with the Android SDK tools. If it doesn't show up in the screenshot, it is an issue with the screen. Or as @dymutaos said, if you seen the blue band as soon as the screen comes on, even when booting the phone, it is an issue with the screen.

Comment: If its on video playback, chances are quite high its related to video codec... possibly DRM :)